# I have $xy$, can i get $x+y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to solve one of my university math problem and it basically came down to this question. If i get an answer or some hints i would be able to solve my original problem.

It sounds pretty simple or dum, but i could not figure it out.

If i have $x$ and $y$ as natural numbers and i know $xy$ value, can i get possible $x+y$ values?

Or maybe you guys know some relations between multiplication and addition results?

I know that there is a rule that:
$$\frac{x+y}2 \ge \sqrt{xy}$$

I was thinking about it for a while now.
Any tips and hints would be thankful.

EDIT: $x$ and $y$ are unknown.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean.. for instance if $xy = 6$ then $x+y = 7$ or $x+y = 5$?

Comment: @Ed_4434 yes, that is what i meant.

Comment: If you know that $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, then $x+y$ is the sum of factor pairs of the product $xy$. The product can only be factored in finitely many ways, so you will have a finite number of possibilities to check.

Comment: Since you know $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, you know the prime decomposition of them. Hence you can figure out, which sums are possible. But to be honest, I would only solve that numerically.

Comment: @ctst It would be faster for larger numbers if he could keep a crib, right?

Comment: A tip: It's difficult to list the factors in order of size: (factors of 360 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 18 um ... did I skip 15)?  and there is no reason to.  It's easier to list them in order of prime factors in increasing power.  1, 2,4,8,3,6,12,24,9,18,36,72,5,10,20,40,15,30,60,120, 45,90,180,360.  The sums are many form 361 to 38.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to a degree that you can classify these.

Let $xy = \prod_{i}p_i^{a_i}$ be the prime factorization of $xy$.

The $x = \prod_{i}p_i^{b_i}$ where $0 \le b_i \le a_i$ and $y = \prod_{i}p_i^{a_i - b_i}$ and $x + y = \prod_{i}p_i^{b_i}+ \prod_{i}p_i^{a_i - b_i}$.  Due to symmetry there are $\lceil \frac{\prod (a_i + 1)}2 \rceil$ solutions.

So for example if $xy = 7  =7^1$ then there is one solution $x+y = 1+7 = 8$.

If $xy = 12 = 2^2*3$ then there are $3$ solutions: $x + y = \{1+12, 2+6, 3+4\}=\{13,8,7\}$

If $xy = 2^6*3^4*5^2=129600$ will have $53$ solutions:

$1+129600= 129601, 2+64800=64802, 4+32400=32404, 8+16200=16208, 16 + 8100=8116, 32+4050=4082, 64 + 2025=2089, 3+43200=43203, 6+21600=21606, .....$.

More reasonable: $xy = 48 = 2^4*3$ will have $5*2/2=5$ solutions:

$1+48 = 49, 2+24=26, 4+12 = 16, 8+6 = 14, 16+3=19$

Comment: Your formula for the number of solutions is ambiguous: If can be read either as $\left\lceil\frac{\prod(a_i+1)}{2}\right\rceil$ or as $\left\lceil\prod\frac{a_i+1}{2}\right\rceil$. I suggest to put the constant factor in front.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the product $P=xy=12$, and you know that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

It's straightforward to find all possible values of $x+y$, and in this case you can write them all out easily.  (I'll assume without loss of generality that $x \leq y$.)

$$x=1, y=12: x+y = 13 \\ x=2, y=6: x+y = 8 \\x = 3,y=4: x+y = 7$$

So it's one of those three values, but without more information (like $y-x=4$) you can't know which one for sure.

Comment: I've seen "I'll assume without loss of generality that  x≤y" a few times, but why can you?

Comment: @JeremyBaziw This is due to symmetry. Note that $xy = yx$, and so it doesn't matter which we choose to be less. We can always switch the variables, so one case is enough. You see this come up a LOT in solving equalities and inequalities, and it is one reason why symmetries make problems so much nicer to work with. Moreover, in this case $x+y=y+x$, and so the symmetry is valid throughout the entire problem

Comment: Another way to put it: If $x\not\le y$ then $y\lt x$, and then if we just switch around which one we are calling $y$ and which $x$, we get $x\lt y$.